# Where did I lose vertex binding?

Tags: opengl

I make OpenGL render framework for my bachelor graduate work.
I created simple Model and Shader classes. But when I tried to render some vertices, they do not render. I saw with an OpenGL profiler, that I haven't vertex data, but in code I bind it.

There's my main class:

```
GLfloat vertex_positions[] = {
        0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};
GLchar *vertexShader = (GLchar *)
                "#version 150\n"
                "\n"
                "in vec2 position;\n"
                "\n"
                "void main()\n"
                "{\n"
                "    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
                "}";
GLchar *fragmentShader = (GLchar *)
        "#version 400 core\n"
        "\n"
        "out vec4 fColor;\n"
        "\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "    fColor = vec4(0.5, 0.4, 0.8, 1.0);\n"
        "}";
static const GLfloat vertex_colors[] =
        {
                1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
        };
Shader shader;
shader.CompileShader(Shader::ShaderType::Fragment, fragmentShader);
shader.CompileShader(Shader::ShaderType::Vertex, vertexShader);
glBindFragDataLocation(*shader.GetProgram(), 0, "fColor");
shader.Link();
Texture texture((GLfloat *) vertex_colors, 16);
Model model (vertex_positions, &shader, &texture);
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    static const float black[] = { 0.2f, 0.3f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, black);
    shader.Bind();
    model.Draw();
    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

And my model class:

```
void Model::Draw() {
glBindVertexArray(_vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

Model::Model(GLfloat meshVert[], int m_size, GLuint vertexInd[], int         
v_size, Shader *material, Texture *texture) {
glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vao);
glBindVertexArray(_vao);

glGenBuffers(1, &_vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*m_size, meshVert,      
   GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(*material->GetProgram(), "position");
glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint) posAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint) posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(*material->GetProgram(), "color");
glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint) colAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint) colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

}
```

P.S.: OpenGL profiler breaks on command `glDrawArrays`, but when I saw data info, it was empty. That's why I think I lost some data bind.

P.S.S: System: macOS Sierra, Intel HD 6000.

Comment: You don't need to bind your vbo for drawing

Comment: Ok,  thank you. But even if I delete bind from draw, it doesn't help.

Comment: Have you a destructor that deletes your GL objects?  And no copy constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Your polygon is wound clock-wise which by default will get culled if `GL_CULL_FACE` is enabled.

Try calling `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);` to disable face culling, it should be disabled by default but it might not be the case due to glfw.

Also try calling `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` before rendering as well.

And your model class instantiation does not match your class constructor:

```
Model model (vertex_positions, &shader, &texture);
Model::Model(GLfloat meshVert[], int m_size, GLuint vertexInd[], int v_size, Shader *material, Texture *texture)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your call to `glDrawArrays()` you're telling it to only draw a single triangle (3 vertices). The last parameter, `count` is the number of indices to draw. From the [man page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml):

> *count*
>
> Specifies the number of indices to be rendered.

Unless you're only drawing a single triangle, you probably need to give it a larger number.

Answer (score 0):

Your shader doesn't use color attribute, but you are trying to use it in C++ code.

Comment out these lines:

```
GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(*material->GetProgram(), "color");
glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint) colAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint) colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't help. Maybe you found any other error in code?